# Ajax Request to Insert Highcharts into Head and Run Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I'm not the best at javascript, and I've been running into some trouble.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

I'm attempting to generate a chart after someone clicks a link with an onclick event.

The head of my document looks like this.

```
<script src="billajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="exporting.js"></script>
```

Billajax.js has many functions, but to simplify, it looks like this.

```
function getl(uid){

if(document.getElementById("votescode")){


    var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    {
      HandleResponse5(xmlHttp.responseText);
      //BELOW GENERATES CHART CODE
          var xmlHttp2 = getXMLHttp();
        xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
        if(xmlHttp2.readyState == 4)
        {
          HandleResponse4(xmlHttp2.responseText);
          dothis();

            }
        }
        xmlHttp2.open("GET", "ajax.php?&p=glv&req="+uid+"&n="+Math.random(), true); 
        xmlHttp2.send(null);

    }
  }
  xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?&p=gl&req="+uid+"&n="+Math.random(), true); 
  xmlHttp.send(null);


}else{

    var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    {
      HandleResponse5(xmlHttp.responseText);

      //BELOW GENERATES CHART CODE
  var xmlHttp2 = getXMLHttp();
    xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if(xmlHttp2.readyState == 4)
    {
      HandleResponse3(xmlHttp2.responseText);
      dothis();

    }
  }
  xmlHttp2.open("GET", "ajax.php?&p=glv&req="+uid+"&n="+Math.random(), true); 
  xmlHttp2.send(null);


    }
  }
  xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?&p=gl&req="+uid+"&n="+Math.random(), true); 
  xmlHttp.send(null);



}

}

function HandleResponse3(response)
{
//var idid = 'waiting';
//toggle_visibility(idid);
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("id", "votescode");
script.innerHTML = response;
document.head.appendChild(script);

}
function HandleResponse4(response)
{
//var idid = 'waiting';
//toggle_visibility(idid);
var el = document.getElementById( 'votescode' ); 
el.parentNode.removeChild( el );

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("id", "votescode");
script.innerHTML = response;
document.head.appendChild(script);


}
function HandleResponse5(response)
{
//var idid = 'waiting';
//toggle_visibility(idid);
document.getElementById('initiative').innerHTML = response;
//var shn = $('.shtn').ThreeDots();
//shn.ThreeDots.update({max_rows:1});
//var bsy = $('.billsy').ThreeDots();
//bsy.ThreeDots.update({max_rows:3});
}
```

The output from the ajax call in getL(uid) is as follows and is inserted into the head of the document successfully.  The html content populated with HandleResponse5 is also inserted correctly.

After I click the link it fires the getl(uid) function which generates the necessary code to insert into the page (highcharts containers), and then it generates the code for highcharts with HandleResponse3 or Handleresponse4, depending on whether the script was previously fired.

The output for the code to generate the highchart is below.  It works if I throw it into jsfiddle, so I can't figure out why I keep receiving the following errors (from chrome console).

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'highcharts'
dothis
(anonymous function)
o jquery.min.js:2
p.add jquery.min.js:2
e.fn.e.ready jquery.min.js:2
e.fn.e.init jquery.min.js:2
e jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous function)
HandleResponse3 billajax.js:310
xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange billajax.js:247
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'highcharts'
dothis
xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange
```

This is the code generated by the call to ajax.php as defined in getl(uid)

```
//CALL FROM BILL AJAX ABOVE WHICH GENERATES CODE BELOW.
xmlHttp2.open("GET", "ajax.php?&p=glv&req="+uid+"&n="+Math.random(), true);

function dothis(){



// Radialize the colors
        Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
            return {
                radialGradient: { cx: 0.4, cy: 0.2, r: 0.7
                                },
                stops: [
                    [0, color],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
                ]
            };
        });
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
                 backgroundColor:'transparent',
                 width:130,height:140,
                 size:'100%'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                size: 200,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                }

            }
        },
        credits:{enabled:false},
        exporting:{enabled:false},
        colors:['#ADD46D','#F1744F','#b9e376','#f2a48d'],
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Supports You',   1],
                ['Opposes You',       1],
                ['Absent on Supporting',    0],
                ['Absent on Opposing',    0]
            ]
        }]
    });
 }




    function dothis2(){



// Radialize the colors
        Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
            return {
                radialGradient: { cx: 0.4, cy: 0.2, r: 0.7
                                },
                stops: [
                    [0, color],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
                ]
            };
        });
       $('#container2').highcharts({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container2',
                 backgroundColor:'transparent',
                 width:130,height:140,
                 size:'100%'
        },
        legend:{
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                size: 200,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                }

            }
        },
        credits:{enabled:false},
        exporting:{enabled:false},
        colors:['#ADD46D','#F1744F','#b9e376','#f2a48d'],
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
               ['Supports You',   0],
                ['Opposes You',       2],
                ['Absent on Supporting',    0],
                ['Absent on Opposing',    0]
            ]
        }]
    });
 }



 $(function () { dothis();dothis2(); });
```

I have successfully implemented a similar solution, but I cannot figure out why this will not work properly when I'm using a similar setup.

Again,  any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have just tried: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/69/ - and adding chart from AJAX works fine. What can I guess is that your paths for Highcharts are wrong.

Comment: Pawel Fus, this is the reason of my confusion... The paths are correct, and the scripts are loaded properly.  I changed them to local copies thinking that it had to do with them loading, and nothing...

Comment: I don't think that example reflects what's happening in the example above.  After watching how your example works, it could be my implementation of the dothis(); function that wraps the creation of the chart?  I'll try stripping that next to see if it makes a difference.  Thanks.

Comment: Attempted to remove the wrapper function dothis();  Still fails with Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'highcharts'

when checking the sources dialogue, highcharts.js is loaded when the page loads, so I'm not sure what would be causing this.

Comment: Are you sure you have one of latest (3.0.x) versions of Highcharts? Could you check that?

Comment: I'm loading highcharts from their server now  http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js, prior to that, it was Highcharts JS v3.0.5 (2013-08-23), both look the same.

Answer (score 0):

Issues was resolved, there was a conflicting library in the body of the page.  The collision of the scripts was causing the error.